# How to Save Excel file in BluePrism?

Tags: blueprism

I have created a new excel file and added data into it from collections, now I want to save this file into a new location(in Drive D).

How should i do that using blue prism?

Answer (score 3):

With the file open( Excel instance running): use an Action stage, select Business Object "MS Excel VBO" and Action "Save Current Workbook As". Drag and drop the Handle item you have been using in to the handle value field. In the File name field you need to enter the full location path and name of the file with its file extension all within double quotes "".   For example "D:\Program Files\NameOfWorkbook.xlsx".Finally, you can go to the Outputs tab and create or drag in a data item that will store the name of the newly saved workbook for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Use MS Excel VBO Built in business object which contains two action like

Save - this would save excel file with default name
Save workbook as - This action you can save file with your given name

As per requirment choose anyone option and your excel sheet would save to particular location in system.